# How to find specific parts of an input's value attribute within a table's specified <tbody> using jQuery

Tags: jquery-selectors

I've rewritten this to make it clearer:

Here's a sample <tbody> in a table (with multiple <tbody>s) I'm working on pulling values from:

```
<table id="#docsTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="docRow">
            <td width="25px"><a class="docAdminFormSubmit edit" name="178" href="#">Edit</a></td>
            <td width="20px"><input type="checkbox" class="chkDeleteDocs" name="removeDocs[]" value="178" /></td>
            <td class="docAndClassTitle">PHP Anthology</td>
            <td>N/A</td>
            <td>the php anthology.pdf</td>
            <td class="numDownloads"><span style="padding-left: 25px;">0</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="docClassesRow">
            <td></td>
            <td width="50px" align="right"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRemoveClasses" name="removeClasses[]" value="180-178" /></td>
            <td colspan="4">ATEST5300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="docClassesRow">
            <td></td>
            <td width="50px" align="right"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRemoveClasses" name="removeClasses[]" value="45-178" /></td>
            <td colspan="4">QTEST7075</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="docClassesRow">
            <td></td>
            <td width="50px" align="right"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRemoveClasses" name="removeClasses[]" value="33-178" /></td>
            <td colspan="4">TEST5220</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to find all <input>s in the table where the second part of the value attribute matches a variable (178 in the above case), iterate through them, and add the **first** part of the value attribute to a comma-separated array (so I would get (180, 45, 33) in the above table).

I have a jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/eventide/8LeeR/ set up with a jQuery statement that gets the **first** input, but I don't know whether I need to use .each() or $.each() to iterate through the <input>s (I can never remember the difference between the two!)

Feel free to modify the jsFiddle to demonstrate an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this give you want you want?
http://jsfiddle.net/75lb/6RPND/

Comment: Awesome! At first glance I thought: "but I need an array of the first number", but you did that, with the output. I just need to replace the right document.output line with the command to add it to the array and I'm good to go. Thanks, Lloyd!

Comment: no probs, glad you got what you needed.. i checked out your website - looks like you're keeping busy! nice one :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the compliment, Lloyd! :) I definitely am keeping busy with my projects!